# How to create form in google app engine and need to store the data in datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine

I need to create a form in google app engine for my user to key in information and the information need to be save in the datastore? So how do I do it?

Comment: This question is not specific to google app engine neither to datastore, but basic web development and integration API to google

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit weak, but I'll try and help you out. I will go step by step:

1/ *need to create a form.*

My guess is: you are talking about a HTML form to submit data to your application. this has nothing to do with app engine you just need to create a standar HTML page with a form and the fields you would like to store  onto the data store, as follow:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="MAPPING_URL" method="POST">
      input: <input type="text" name="user" />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Basically here I just created a simple form with one input "text" field and a Submit button to send out the "action" paramenter using the "method" parameter. For more information about forms, please take a look at: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

2/ *information need to be save in the datastore.*

To make this happen you need to do a couple of this:

- Create a Model for the entity you would like to save on the Datastore.
- Create a handler that would received the request and save the entity.

Please take your time and read up the getting started guide: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/ this will clear out your doubts and give you a better understanding on how to build applications on App Engine.

Best,
Jose Montes de Oca

Comment: Good answer to a vague question.

Comment: For Java: here is the getting started guide: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/